# How can I use a button to add +1 to a field using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS. For my first project I want to create a small scorekeeping application. I am taking data from a JSON file then I want to update it on the screen depending on who scores.

I can't seem to figure out how to update the specific goal field using Angular. My current application pushes a new row to the scoresheet:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

function ScoreKeeper($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('json/hometeam.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.hometeam = data;
  });

  $scope.addGoal = function() {
    $scope.hometeam.push({goals: +1});
  };
}
```

This is the table I am currently using:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>Player ID</th>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>GP</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>PIM</th>
            <th>Goal</th>
            <th>Assist</th>
            <th>Assist</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="player in hometeam" >
                <td>{{player.playerid}}</td>
                <td>{{player.no}}</td>
                <td>{{player.name}}</td>
                <td>{{player.gp}}</td>
                <td>{{player.goals}}</td>
                <td>{{player.assists}}</td>
                <td>{{player.pim}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-small" name="add-goal" type="button" ng-click="addGoal()"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button></td>                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to be able to click addGoal for the specific player, and then update their goal total. Right now, the current function is creating a new row with goal being 1 and all the other fields are empty.

I'm quite lost on this one, the data is rendering correctly on refresh, however, my update function is not. I know .push() is not the correct method, however I can't seem to find a good resource for Angular to figure out what would be the right method to use. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new array item with push, you need to increment the goals property of the associated player item.  `ng-click="addGoal(player)"`.

```
$scope.addGoal = function (player) {
    player.goals += 1;
};
```

or just

`ng-click="player.goals = player.goals + 1"`

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense looking at it now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add element into `player.goals`, correct?

Then you can do:

```
<button ng-click="addGoal($index)">
```

in js:

```
$scope.addGoal = function(index) { $scope.hometeam[index].goals++; };
```